# How to generate HTML table from SQL table in .NET

Tags: javascript, sql, .net, telerik

I would like to have a dynamic HTML page, I would only have to give it the DB connectionString and the table name, and it will create an HTML page that present the table data and allow to edit cells. (of course updating the data in the DB)

Maybe Telerik have something close, but I could not find one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use scaffolding technique with Entity Framework.

This tutorial will help you:

[enter link description here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/generating-views)